# How do I edit this CSS such that there is space for 5 images in one row

Tags: html, css

How do I adjust my .image-card such that there can be 5 images in one row, and the 6th image should go in second row

As of now I have 2 images in my database and the second image is going in the second row

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.image-card {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.image-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div className="container" key={item._id}>
  <div className="image-row">
    <div className="image-card">
      <img src={item.image} alt="Image 1" className="image" />
      <div className="image-title">{item.caption}</div>
      <div className="profile-info">
        <div className="username">{item.postedBy && item.postedBy.username}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a image of your problem please?

Comment: You can add padding on `.image-card`.

Comment: Use `class="..."` instead of `className="..."` as tag attribute.

Comment: @schmauch Probably OP use some js framework like React

Comment: @schmauch I am using Reactjs

Comment: @ArmanMoalemi I added the output

Answer (score 0):

You should compute the right value for `flex-basis` and `max-width`. As there are 5 columns with 4 gaps of size 20 px between them, the right value is `max-width: calc(20% - 16px)`.

`- 16px` because 16 equals to 4/5 of 20px.

Comment: I tried that too, didn't work

Comment: You will need to add `min-width: 0;` as well, then it should work. https://jsfiddle.net/9cmogn2p/